# Is it possible to real-time synchronize 2 SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization

I have an application that runs on server A and the database is on the same server
there is a backup server B which I use in case the server A is down

the application will remain unchanged but the data in the DB is changing constantly

Is there a way to synchronize those 2 databases real-time automatically?

currently I wait till all the users are gone so I can manually backup and restore in the backup server.

Edit: When I said real-time I didn't mean it literally, I can handle up to one hour delay but the faster sync the better.

- My databases are located on 2 servers on the same local network.
- 2 of them are SQL Server 2008, the main DB is on windows server 2008
- the backup is on windows server 2003
- A web application (intranet) is using the DB
- I can use sql agent (if that can help)

I don't know what kind of details could be useful to solve this, kindly tell me what can help. Thanks.

**Edit**: I need to sync all the tables and table only.
the second database is writable not read-only

Comment: If you really mean *"real-time"* you need a new OS ;-)

Comment: not real-time but.... real-time ;). I can handle 1 hour delay or less.

Comment: There are many ways to keep SQL Server databases in synch with latencies from 24 hours down to about a 1 to 5 minutes.  You'll need to give us more specifics to help distinguish between all of the possibilities.  True "real-time" (latency less than a second) requires very special software and custom configuration.

Comment: 1) Does everything in the databases need to be synched, or only part of them?  2) Do both databases need to be writeable, or could one of them be read-only?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Edit again, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is [Peer to Peer Transactional Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

From the link:

> Peer-to-peer replication provides a scale-out and high-availability
>   solution by maintaining copies of data across multiple server
>   instances, also referred to as nodes. Built on the foundation of
>   transactional replication, peer-to-peer replication propagates
>   transactionally consistent changes in near real-time. This enables
>   applications that require scale-out of read operations to distribute
>   the reads from clients across multiple nodes. Because data is
>   maintained across the nodes in near real-time, peer-to-peer
>   replication provides data redundancy, which increases the availability
>   of data.

Comment: I will have a look at this, I think it's what I want, thanks.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the right path for the OP, given the requirements, though I wouldn't necessarily limit it to Transactional Replication, as Merge Replication may be sufficient and tends to scale a little bit better.

Comment: Peer to peer replication is only available in SQL Server Enterprise edition.