# Multiple tenants with Entity Framework Core and SQL Server 2017 in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2017

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application which uses Entity Framework Core 2.1 and  SQL Server 2017 (Web edition). I read a lot of how to solve problem with multiple tenants, but more or less the answer is:

> it depends on your application, setup.

**Setup:**

- every client gets a new IIS site with own configuration for database
- some tables (client defines on setup which one) must be shared between tenants, for example: it has common tables for users, groups, rights, user-settings, but separate for offers, prices, events ...
- every table has identity column (`int`) which is the primary key
- all tenants have exactly the same table structure (when upgrading client, all tenants should update all tables structures)
- I am using a code-first approach with EF Core

**Options:**

1. separate database for every client and tenant (Db name `client_tenant`)
2. separate database for every client and use schema for tenant (Db name `client.tenant`)
3. separate database for every client and use column in every table (`TenantId`)

**Details:**

I know every option has cons and pros, so here is more information about the setup:

- every client has 1 or more (up to 1000) tenants (average around 20)
- clients must share some tables between tenants
- there is approximately 500 hundred tables, approx 10 of them are shareable (common) between tenants (those clients who has the need to share)
- biggest table can produce 10 million records per year

**Pros / cons** as I see them:

1. separate databases (separate Db for tenant):

   - pros

     - security
     - table structure changes are fully supported by EF (migrations)
     - tables are transparent
   - cons

     - not so easy to [dynamically change database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836102/asp-net-core-change-ef-connection-string-when-user-logs-in)
     - left join with EF Core over databases [is not supported](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6089) yet *(related with next point)*
     - no solution at the moment how to solve common tables (users, groups, rights, user-settings)<sup>1</sup>.
     - a lot of databases: `client1_tenant1`, `client1_tenant2`, ..., `client2_tenant1` ...
2. separate schemes (1Db, separate scheme for tenant):

   - pros

     - there is no problem with sharing data (I can have one default schema for common tables)
     - secure (less then 1. options)
   - cons

     - not so easy to [dynamically change schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core/39631404)
     - I can not use schemas for separating tables in modules
     - managing tables structure changes with EF<sup>2</sup>
3. `TenantId` column (1 Db, 1 scheme):

   - pros

     - fully supported by EF Core - [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters), migrations ...
   - cons

     - can have very large tables (1 client * 500 tenants * 2000000 records * 10 years = 100 billions rows in 10 years - the biggest client, biggest table)
     - security<sup>3</sup>
     - potential performance problems
     - harder to maintain (very large tables - they aren't transparent)

**Summary:**

Which approach (1, 2 or 3) should I choose if I:

- am using EF Core
- need to share some tables between tenants (sync should happened in less then a minute).<sup>4</sup>
- can have very large tables
- I have more then 500 tables, and they logically belong to 1 module

**Related topics:** (just to prove I did my homework and search for duplicates)

- Sync 2 tables to different databases: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613983/sql-server-synchronizing-2-tables-on-2-different-databases), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837585/how-to-sync-tables-between-two-databases-in-both-directions-sql-server-2008-r2)
- Multi tenant - code first in [EF 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458943/multi-tenant-with-code-first-ef6) (not Core)
- Migrations with [multiple Db schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205602/ef-core-migrations-with-multiple-db-schemas)
- [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961979/which-multi-tenant-approach-is-recommended) with very different setup
- and many many more, so that I can understand better the problem and possible solutions

**References:**

<sup>1</sup>  One way is [SQL Server replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017) - problems with identity.
Each client has some common tables to manage rights about witch tenant can see, edit, settings which columns want to see for some table ...

<sup>2</sup> Not sure if this is even possible. Probably I should call in `for` loop `context.Database.Migrate();` for every tenant.

<sup>3</sup> All data belongs to the same table, so bug where one tenant would see data of another tenant is awful but not devastating. Also with [global filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) this risk is minimised.

<sup>4</sup> I could write API to sync changes in code (some background thread), because these changes doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @Sir What is your question?

Comment: Which approach should I use / is supported by EF, based on my setup.

Comment: Are there any additional pros/cons if I go with option 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

> Yea, it depends on your application.

I'd go with 1.

> some tables (client defines on setup which one) must be shared between
>   tenants, for example: it has common tables for users, groups, rights,
>   user-settings, but separate for offers, prices, events

If you need tables for settings, user management, groups, rights, etc you should create a separate database per client that will have one purpose: user handling - crud, rights, groups, checks, etc.

You'll need to pass this information along as claims or any other suitable authorization system.

So I'll create like a client1_user_management, client1_tenant1, client1_tenant2, etc

If you're using claims (jwt, cookies) or any other way to pass along groups, rights, etc you won't need `left join with EF Core over databases`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

As for the other con: `not so easy to dynamically change database`;

In order to avoid this type of configuration, you can inject your database based on a subdomain or something like that:

```
public void Configure()
{
  Dictionary<string, string> connStrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  connStrs.Add("DB1", Configuration["Data:DB1Connection:ConnectionString"]);
  connStrs.Add("DB2", Configuration["Data:DB2Connection:ConnectionString"]);
  DbContextFactory.SetConnectionString(connStrs);
}
```

You'll probably have one application that will handle multiple clients/multiple tenants. It's useful to identify and inject one client & one tenant per request.

Receiving request for: https://client1.myapp.com/tenant1 -> i can identify client1 and tenant1 and i can figure out database name (hardcoded like client1_tenant1 or configured if you have a tenant management system). As i can figure out a database name, I'll use that to create a `DBContext` per request (scoped: [What is the difference between services.AddTransient, service.AddScope and service.AddSingleton methods in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi)).

P.S: This is an opinion based on current information. I'll try to push this solution if it's possible.

Comment: I just discover that Foreign-Key also doesn't work over databases. The biggest problem is users table. Yes, I am using JWT.

Comment: Yep. I won't go down to that path. You'll need to handle a lot of ugly sync issues.